# How can I batch replace one string at start of filename with string from end of filename?

Tags: command-line, filename

I am looking for a command that I can use with Kubuntu's terminal (Konsole).

**(Edit) I figured out how to remove the useless last 13 characters in the filename, so what would the script be if I want to replace "Karaoke" with the artist name in the filename is "Karaoke" + space + "song title" + " - " + "artist name" + .mp4?**

Is there a way to replace the word "Karaoke" with "artist name" for all the files in a directory? Thanks in advance.

Here are the example filenames that Oli requested:

```
Karaoke A Spoonful Of Sugar - Mary Poppins
Karaoke Ain't No Stoppin' Us Now - McFadden & Whitehead
Karaoke Ain't Nobody - Chaka Khan
Karaoke A Tisket, A Tasket - Ella Fitzgerald
```

Comment: Please show us an actual example file name, it is hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Yeah a directory list sample that we could replicate would be good to show you answer that definitely work.

Comment: What you need are called [backreferences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences). Oli has used them quite nicely.

Comment: The following aexample shows that sometimes there is a hyphen or dash in the 11-character string: Karaoke Alegria - Cirque du Soleil -BVdI-KGc0NI

Comment: I am going to try to find all of those dashes in the 11-character string by putting the filenames in a spreadsheet and do a text to columns action using dashes as a separator and then sort unless someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little over the top but it works here:

```
$ rename 's/^Karaoke (.+) - (.+) - \w{11}\.mp4$/$2 - $1.mp4/' * -vn
Karaoke banana - cher - 12345678901.mp4 renamed as cher - banana.mp4
```

You'll need to knock the `-n` off the end to make it actually rename files. I've left the safety on.

What we're *doing* here is finding any files that match this pattern, capturing the artist and track from within that pattern and then replacing the whole thing with those two groups (and some formatting and the extension).

I can't predict what it would do if you had artists with `-` in their names. Probably nothing good, but single dashes (without the spaces) should be fine.

Comment: I tried various suggested commands but they didn't work.

Comment: Here is a link to a screen shot. http://imgur.com/Dt8NJHi

Comment: Please update your question with real examples so I can test. I need a copy and paste of `ls` (or a portion of it).

Answer (score -1):

if all are `mp4` extension use this

> rename "s/^Karaoke (.+)-(.+)-\w{11}.mp4$/\$2-\$1.mp4/" *.mp4 -n

if you don't have spaces before and after the `-` symbol,
otherwise use the @oli example

@terdon my mistake...

Comment: @user295082 don't try it! Make a copy first. This will simply rename all files to the literal string `artist name`. Alex, the OP wants to extract the name from the file name.